# What is the correct way to get the messaging token for FCM in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Good evening!

I am looking to add Firebase cloud messaging to my project (Android, Java). I have followed the documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token
to a tee, but am still having issues retrieving the messaging token. Android studio claims **Cannot resolve method 'getToken' in 'FirebaseMessaging'** and will not compile. I assume I need to write a method getToken(), but can not find any documentation on what that method should do.

Here is my class, which extends FirebaseMessagingService as the documentation describes.

```
public class PushNotificationManager extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public String MT;

    public PushNotificationManager() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to get token");
                    return;
                }
                MT = task.getResult();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        MT =  token;
        System.out.println("Refreshed token: " + token);
    }
}
```

I also override onNewToken(), per the docs, but I never get a print to the logs.

Here is the service I added to the manifest:

```
        <service android:name=".PushNotificationManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

There are a number of old stack overflow articles about this subject, but none have worked, most are older than a year, and use InstanceID() which is now depreciated.

Any suggestions? Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to my conversation below with Doug, I have solved my issue. Firstly, I focused on onNewToken() in this class, and deleted my getToken() request in the constructor.

```
public class PushNotificationManager extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public String MT;

    public PushNotificationManager() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        MT =  token;
        System.out.println("Refreshed token: " + token);
    }
}
```

This, in combination with the updates to the manifest file, logs the messaging token on app start up **After a complete reinstall**. Now, to store the token in Firebase RTB, I need to access this after I initialize the database. So I added a method in my database class, which is called after the database is initialized. It looks like this:

```
    private void setMT()
    {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get new Instance ID token
                        String MT = (String) task.getResult().getToken();
                        System.out.println("Messaging token: "+MT);
//Now I can save it to the RTB
                    }
                });
    }
```

And now its working! Thanks for the help, Doug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are overriding `onNewToken` in a registered subclass of `FirebaseMessagingService`, then you don't need anything else to get a token.  You either fetch it on demand with `getToken`, or you receive it via callback with `onNewToken`.  There is little reason to do both (especially in the same class), unless you absolutely know you need to.

If you don't get a callback to onNewToken, then you probably didn't fully [follow the instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) and add your subclass of `FirebaseMessagingService` as an Android service in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I do have my manifest updated with a new service, and will update my question with the new service, perhaps I have an error in it.

Comment: You still shouldn't be using both techniques at the same time in the same class.  That doesn't seem to be helpful.  Focus on one or the other.

Comment: thanks! I removed the getToken() and am just running an empty constructor. Now When I uninstall and reinstall the app, I get a log with the messaging token. My issue now is that this happens BEFORE any of my other code, so I can not write this to the database in the onNewToken method, since my database is not initialized yet. I want to add the messing token to my firebase database for this user so I can use it with cloud functions. How do I access this?